# Ищу 3D движок на XNA, для создания игры на Windows Phone 7

Tags: xna, windows-phone-7, разработка-игр, c#

Какие движки существуют на данный момент для создания игр на Windows Phone 7, плюсы, минусы, подводные камни. На sourceforge есть много разных проектов, но все они весьма сырые, и в основном, ориентированны на 2D игры. Из коммерческих я нашел только один достойный проект: [SunBurn](http://www.synapsegaming.com/products/sunburn/engine/). Из опенсорсных — ни одного.

Comment: Вот еще один: http://deltaengine.net/ Поддерживает WP7/iOS/Android/PC/Linux/Max/XBOX, но пока только в закрытой бете, выйти должен к концу года.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Balder 3D](http://balder.codeplex.com/)  тоже не плохой, пожалуй лучший из опенсорс.